# Property Function Returns Property Object instead of Value

Tags: python, properties, static-methods, class-method

I am having an issue with property methods in my code.  I'm building a library and I'm making the tests for it.  Part of the testing is to make sure the library handles the json api response properly.  I have a very large and long amount of json responses that I consolidated into one file that I want to reference in my tests.  My first thought is to make separate classes and property functions that return the json for each call.  Ideally I wanted to make these `staticmethods` and `classmethods` so that I wouldn't have to instantiate the object.  i.e. `return_value=call_json.Login.correct_login`.  The problem is when I reference the function in my tests it returns the property object instead of the dictionary.

For example:

```py
from . import call_json
import pytest

LOGIN_CALL = call_json.Login.correct_call

Class TestLogin:
    @pytest.fixture
    def api_mock(self, caplog):
        (api call mock & objects initialized)

    def test_correct_login(self, api_mock):
        self.mock_api.return_value = (LOGIN_CALL, 200)
        # The api call responds with a tuple of (dict, 200)
```

call_json.py:

```py
class Login:

    @property
    @staticmethod
    def correct_call():
        return {code: 0, token: 'tk', ID: 'id'}
```

The test fails because the LOGIN_CALL returns a property object instead of dictionary.  What am I doing wrong?

Is there a more efficient or pythonic way to format the call_json.py to allow for dictionaries or lists to be easily accessed across many files?

Comment: What's the point of your class if you aren't going to instantiate it? In any case, to do something like what you are trying to do, the property would have to exist on the metaclass. You probably don't need a class at all, just some variables in the modules global scope.

Comment: There are some classes and methods that need to be instantiated.  Making them variables and importing was what I ended up doing with most of them.  I was just curious what makes the method return the property object instead of the actual return value.

Comment: Because properties *work on instances* through the descriptor protocol. If you access any property on the class then, of course, you simply get the property object itself. To get a property to work on a class, you need to put it on the class of the class, i.e. the *metaclass*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix it by changing the order of the decorators and using `@classmethod` instead of `@staticmethod`:

*Requires python 3.9+*

```
class Login:
    @classmethod
    @property
    def correct_call(cls):
        return {'code': 0, 'token': 'tk', 'ID': 'id'}
```

---

Looks like the above method is planned to be [deprecated](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/functions.html#classmethod) in 3.11+. Remind me to update if indeed they go ahead with this.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I ultimately found this was a bad practice, even if not depreciated. Properties are meant for getting and setting instance attributes since they are local to the instance.